# why we give in query sql 1=0

Tags: mysql

I have seen in some programmers use 1=0 in where condition for select query , why they use this condition.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [why would you use WHERE 1=0 statement in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9140606/why-would-you-use-where-1-0-statement-in-sql)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The only possible use for that would be to prevent the query from returning any rows. I've done it occasionally for testing "no results found" type logic.

Answer (score 16):

in sql server, you can quickly create a copy of a table without any data like this

```
select * into Newtable
from Oldtable
where 1 = 0
```

this will create a new table with the same structure as the old table

Another option is to return an empty resultset

Comment: Even simpler with same effect:
`select * into Newtable
from Oldtable
where 0`

Comment: I want to confirm that this is the same what is done using Oracle as well, not just limited to SQL Server.

Comment: SELECT TOP 0 * into newtable from oldtable will give the same results without the confusing math.

Answer (score 5):

I have seen some utilities use that syntax to gather metadata about a table.  They may run a query such as `select * from sometable where 1=0` to "efficiently" get the columns from the table without any data.

Comment: Wouldn't work in MySQL, I think. That's what `SHOW COLUMNS` is for.

Comment: @ceejayoz: Thanks for the information.  I did not know that about MySQL; I assumed (apparently incorrectly) that it would return an empty result set, which would still have the columns.  It does work in other SQL implementations (a few at least).

Answer (score 0):

I've used this in code when generating the SQL based on a checkbox list of values.  For example, if I allow the user to pick from a list of fruit:

Apples
Oranges
Pears

...and they select Apples and Oranges, my pseudo code looks like:

```
string sqlWhere = "select * from fruit where 1 = 0"
if (FruitList.Any()) {
   sqlWhere += " or code in ("
   foreach (Fruit in FruitList)
      sqlWhere += string.Format("'{0}',");
   /*Add the close parens*/
   sqlWhere = sqlWhere.Substring(0,sqlWhere.Length-2) + ")";
}
```

which will only return the values the user selected.  If they don't select any fruit, then no results are returned.

*Please note this code does not account for SQL Injection.  Just an example of why you might see the

```
where 1 = 0
```

Comment: I think your AND needs to become an OR.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a query like this as a 'ping' to check if your connection to the database is still open and the database is healthy and so on - if you get no results, it is, but if you get some sort of error, there's a problem. You'd write the query against some sort of system table. Depending on your database, you might be able to do something simpler - in PostgreSQL, you can just say `select 1;`, and in Oracle, i've seen `select 1 from dual;`. If your database doesn't have the ability to handle free-floating expressions in selects, and has no equivalent of dual, you could do something like `select * from sometable where 0 = 1;`.