# Scope Search in Laravel returning all results from empty request()

Tags: laravel

I am working with Scope Search and cannot figure out why my ternary operator is working like it is.

I have the following in my view:

```
<form action='/search-results' method='GET'>

{{ csrf_field() }}

<div style="background-color:white">

<div class="container py-5">
    <div class="input-group custom-search-form md-form mt-0">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="city" placeholder="City...">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="search" placeholder="Search...">
                <span class="input-group-btn">
    <button class="btn btn-default-sm" type="submit">
        Submit
    </button>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</form>
```

I have the following in my Controller:

```
    public function index()
{

    {
        //The search() function is accessed using 'scopeSearch' within NPIData Model


        $providers = NPIData::lookup()->orderBy('NPI')->paginate(20);

        return view('inc.searchresults', compact('providers'));
    }
```

I have the following in my NPIData model:

```
    public function scopeLookup($query)
{


    //this says if the request is NOT empty, return $query (which would be an empty query), otherwise return $query with all the conditions listed

    return empty(request())  ? $query :  $query->where('NPI', 'like', '%'.request()->search.'%')
                                                ->where('Entity Type Code', '=', '1')
                                                ->where('Provider Business Mailing Address City Name', '=', request()->zip)
                                                ->orWhere('Provider First Name', 'like', '%'.request()->search.'%')
                                                ->orWhere('Provider Last Name (Legal Name)', 'like', '%'.request()->search.'%');

                                            }
```

}

When a search term is entered in both the 'city' and 'search' text inputs, the $query executes correctly.  However, if one or both inputs are left blank, the $query returns everything from my NPIData table.  If one or both inputs are left blank, I want my $query to return nothing so the search results are blank.  I assume I have to change something in the second part of my ternary operator but cannot figure out what that should be.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [where 1 < 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9140606/why-would-you-use-where-1-0-statement-in-sql) which is pretty standard way to get empty result

```php
public function scopeLookup($query)
{
    //this says if the request is NOT empty, return $query (which would be an empty query), otherwise return $query with all the conditions listed

    return empty(request()) ? $query->whereRaw('1 < 0') : $query->where('NPI', 'like', '%'.request()->search.'%')
        ->where('Entity Type Code', '=', '1')
        ->where('Provider Business Mailing Address City Name', '=', request()->zip)
        ->orWhere('Provider First Name', 'like', '%'.request()->search.'%')
        ->orWhere('Provider Last Name (Legal Name)', 'like', '%'.request()->search.'%');
}
```